# Writing a simple macro

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to write a simple macro but since I am new to writing macros, I'm finding it very challenging.

There are three sheets in the workbook. When I open the workbook, I just want page 1 (START) to show up and only after they click enable content, it should show up the other two sheets. This is the code I have tried, could you let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'Step 1: Declare your variables
  Dim ws As Worksheet
'Step 2: Unhide the Starting Sheet
  Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible
'Step 3: Start looping through all worksheets
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'Step 4: Check each worksheet name
  If ws.Name <> "START" Then
'Step 5: Hide the sheet
  ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
  End If
'Step 6: Loop to next worksheet
  Next ws
'Step 7: Save the workbook
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Step 1: Declare your variables
  Dim ws As Worksheet
'Step 2: Start looping through all worksheets
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'Step 3: Unhide All Worksheets
  ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
'Step 4: Loop to next worksheet
  Next ws
'Step 5: Hide the Start Sheet
  Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Comment: To start with, forget about your BeforeClose procedure. You don't care about hidden sheets while the workbook is closed. Your interest in the topic doesn't start until the workbook is opened.

Comment: @Variatus - the `BeforeClose` will hide those sheets though, so next time workbook is open it will not be shown. It's a way of forcing the action you want to have when workbook is opened again by user

Comment: What is happening now that you don't want to happen? Like, what is the code currently doing that you don't desire?

Comment: check out this link for the "enable content" prob https://superuser.com/questions/1290405/use-vba-to-detect-if-a-excel-is-displaying-the-enable-content-security-warning

Comment: "Next time the workbook is opened" the Workbook_Open procedure will run. It's job is to over-ride whatever settings there are in the workbook, including those you might enter before closing. So, I admit, if that procedure can't run (f.i. because the user disabled macros) the visibility set before closing would take on significance. However, bear in mind that no Excel project is a data vault. A determined user can open any sheet in any Excel workbook, including very hidden and protected ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your Workbook_Open procedure makes all sheets visible (good, because you should avoid hiding all) and then hide the START sheet (bad, because you want this one sheet to be visible). Try this code instead.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next                    ' in case there is no such sheet
    With Worksheets("START")
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With

    If Err.Number = 0 Then                  ' abandon if there is no START
        For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Ws.Name <> "START" Then
                Ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If
        Next Ws
    End If
End Sub
```